# C# - auto-detect file encoding?

Tags: c#, text, encoding, utf-8

**actual question:**

What is the best practice to modify text-files without changing their encoding?

**Background info:**

I am a bit ashamed that I fail to do this. What I actually want to do is what any texteditor does: Open, modify and save a large number of text-based files, without accidently modifying more than I want to.

```
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, s);
```

This will both use a default encoding. I can also provide a specific encoding as parameter. Both is not what I want. How do I easily autodetect the encoding to be able to read and write without changing it?

Best wishes,
Janis

Comment: _"How do I easily autodetect the encoding"_ - there is no such thing. It is not trivial, and all approaches are best-effort. If your modification only inserts or replaces ASCII text (character codes <= 127), you could treat any non-Unicode text file as binary (as Unicode detection is _somewhat_ easier) - barring character sets that don't even deal in ASCII.

Comment: Then how do texteditor-tools manage to work properly?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible, I'm saying it's not trivial. There can always be some ambiguity.

Comment: Thanks. This is supposed to be a rather common problem: How come the System.IO-Library does not provide the means for a simple "best-effort solution" and instead uses only the default encodings?

Comment: I guess because it's not deterministic. I wouldn't want to support such a feature, and I guess MS didn't either.